# LinearLayout as custom button, OnClickListener never called

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I've been using the common Android Button with both icon (drawableTop) and text. It works really poorly if you want to have a non-standard size button, so I decided to make a custom button with a LinearLayout having the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   style="@style/ButtonHoloDark"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:gravity="center" 
   android:clickable="true" 
   android:focusable="true"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/buttonIcon"  
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:duplicateParentState="true" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/buttonText"  
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:duplicateParentState="true"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:textColor="@color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The layout is used by a custom class:

```
public class CustomIconButton extends LinearLayout {
    public CustomIconButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setAttributes(context, attrs);
    LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_icon_button, this, true);
}

...
```

But when I set an OnClickListener on my button in its parent layout it never gets called. I can only receive clicks if a set the listener to the ImageView and/or TextView. This leads to two possible effects when the button is clicked:

1. The click is inside the ImageView or the TextView. The click is registered ok, but the buttons state drawable doesn't change i.e. it doesn't appear depressed.
2. The click is inside the "empty area" of the button. The click is not registered, but the state drawable works ok.

Neither of these is feasible. I've played around with the following attributes on the LinearLayout or its children, but none really seem to have any effect whether true or false:

- duplicateParentState
- clickable
- focusable

There doesn't seem to be any reasonable way to get the LinearLayout parent receive clicks instead of its children. I've seen some possible solutions overriding dispatchTouchEvent or onInterceptTouchEvent on the custom component itself, but that really seems like a big mess if I have to start analyzing touch events to identify proper clicks.

So OnClickListener on a LinearLayout with children = no go?

EDIT:
This is how I currently insert the buttons into my Fragment's main layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

...

<com.package.CustomIconButton
        android:id="@+id/someButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        mynamespace:buttonIcon="@drawable/someIcon"
        mynamespace:text="@string/str_someText" />

 ...
```

And the button is bound in the Fragment's code as follows:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);

    View customButton = v.findViewById(R.id.goButton);     
    customButton.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);

    ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you set the listener on the correct `LinearLayout`(as you have two, the parent and the one from the inflated layout). Some time ago I made a similar component and the listener worked with no problems(I don't know what you have in those styles). The only difference was that I didn't add a (not needed) `LinearLayout`, instead I used the `merge` tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/buttonIcon"  
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/buttonText"  
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"              
       android:textColor="@color/white" />

</merge>
```

and set the style on the parent `LinearLayout`.

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow you. If I use merge, how can treat the button as a single view? What do you mean with the parent LinearLayout in the case of merge? (I edited my question to show how I currently use the button.)

Comment: @ohra There is no need for the inner `LinearLayout`. This article about the merge tag should help you understand http://android-developers.blogspot.ro/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-by.html . The style would have to be moved to layout where you use the `CustomIconButton`(in the fragment/activity) layout.

Comment: Ok, thanks, now I understand the LinearLayout inside LinearLayout problem. I replaced the button's LinearLayout with merge, moved style and some other attributes up to the main layout, but for some reason the buttons are now totally dead. They look fine style-wise, but the state drawable (coming from the style) doesn't work and the click is still not registered. What might I still have wrong?

Comment: @ohra I've made a little sample(with no style attached to the `LinearLayout`) regarding your code and the `OnClickListener` works. You can find it here https://gist.github.com/3599974 . See what you do different from the code I posted and if you can make any adjustments(maybe the style could be problematic, but the listener should be triggered).

Comment: Found the problem (some leftover code from my previous experiments with event dispatching) and it works perfectly now. Styles included. A huge thank you, @Luksprog.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a `transparent child` for your linear layout and set it's dimension `fill_parent` then register `onClickListener` for it,so when user click on it,it will respond.For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@null" />

</LinearLayout>
```

onCreate():

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("CLICKED!");
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Did you mean setting the transparent background on the LinearLayout's children? Since setting it on the LinearLayout itself will screw up the state drawable. Setting it on the children certainly helps, now I have a consistent response from the state drawable no matter where I click on the button! The LinearLayout's OnClickListener doesn't fire, though.

Comment: Yes, setting the OnClickListeners on the button's child views surely is one possible option. It does take a bit of more effort to place the children correctly without leaving any gaps or distorting the icon by using fill_parent. This is probably how I'd do it if I can't get the LinearLayout's own click listener working.